# Angular 2 Routing - How to handle route match conflicts?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two routes I'd like to match for, but they conflict with each other. I have a generic route where `path: ":page"`, but I have another specific route `path: "id_token"`. Ideally the router would check first to see if `path: "id_token"` is a match before then reverting to `path: ":page"`.

```
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [

    // If this route is a match then use this config
    {
        path: "id_token",
        pathMatch: "prefix",
        redirectTo: ":page/d",
    },

    // Otherwise use this config
    {
        path: ":page",
        component: "PageComponent",
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CanActive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) for this

```
@Injectable()
class MyCanActivate implements CanActivate {
    constructor() {}
    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
        return true/false; //to active/deactive your route
    }
}
```

Then for your routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Route[] = [

    // If this route is a match then use this config
    {
        path: "id_token",
        pathMatch: "prefix",
        redirectTo: ":page/d",
        canActivate: [MyCanActivate]
    },

    // Otherwise use this config
    {
        path: ":page",
        component: "PageComponent",
    }
];
```